# MySQL query with multiple count statements in a effective way

Tags: mysql, performance, count

Let's have 4 simple tables:

```
TABLE region (id, name)
TABLE country (id, name, region_id) 
TABLE organization (id, name, country_id) 
TABLE person (id, name, organization_id)
```

I want to make a query, where I would have:

- Region name
- Person count for region
- Country name
- Person count for country
- Organization name
- Person count for organization
- Person name

For instance:
Europe, 20, Slovakia, 2, University of Life, 1, Somebody

How can I make those counts in a effective way in MySQL?

I have a huge query, where I have inline selects for each count, but this is not at all efficient. I was considering sum with case, but I don't quite grasp the concept if I have thousands of organizations with different names...

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT r.name as region, count(DISTINCT r.id) as region_total,
        c.name as city, count(DISTINCT c.id) as country_total,
        o.name as organization, count(DISTINCT o.id) as organization_total,
        COUNT(p.id) as person_total
 FROM region r
 JOIN country c
   on r.id= c.region_id
 JOIN organization o
   ON c.id = o.country_id
 JOIN person p 
   ON o.id p.organization_id
 GROUP BY r.id, c.id, o.id
 ORDER BY r.id, c.id, o.id
```

I dont see how you want to include a person name here